# jquery draggable: drag and drop elements with snap but no overlay?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, element

you can see my code right here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pghqv/6/

i have 3 black bars that can be dragged and dropped. they even snap to each other when they are close enough - that's exactly what i want to have.

the last feature i want to add is that it's not possible to stack to bars over each other. Kind of a hittest, whenever an element is dragged upon another one and the mouse is released it should snap to the outer edges of the bar underneath.

any idea how i can make that work?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have better results if you use "sortable", along with a "grid". See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-grid

Description: grid Default:false
Snaps the sorting element or helper to a grid, every x and y pixels. Array values: [x, y]

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/LN2rQ/

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what i don't want :) thank you. i already tried the sortable method, however i don't want to have a grid like list that you can sort. i want to drag and drop the items vertically anywhere on my body. i just don't want to allow to overlapping elements.

Comment: Why not use the "out" event to determine when the item isn't in the list, then just let it be draggable onto the page.  When it's dragged "over" the list, put it back.